# Latest OS X update broke my preexisting dual screen setup (10.12.6)

Tags: display, macos, displayport, dual-screen

I just updated my MacBook Pro mid-2012 Retina 15in to the latest OS X and now that I've rebooted it doesn't want to go into dual screen anymore. I've used this setup for a long time now (couple of years) and it's never been a problem. I'm connected with a mini-DP to DP cable, and I've tried to reset the PRAM/NVRAM already.

When I connect the cable to my Mac the MacBooks screen starts flickering a few times, then I get a "No signal from cable" message on my other screen and everything goes back to normal on my MB.

I'm really at a loss as to what could possibly be the reason, are there any logs I could look at to see what might be happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT: I tried booting into safe mode and back, didn't work either. I'm looking for a HDMI cable but may have to buy one to test if that works.

EDIT2: I managed to find a HDMI cable and it works fine with that but not with the miniDP to DP cable. Weird.

Comment: not clear to me, to what are you connecting your Mac to with the cable ? what device/screen ?

Comment: I'm connecting it to my secondary screen... hence the title dual screen.

Comment: sorry my question was not clear. What is the second screen ? is it an Apple, or what ? you use a cable to connect your MacBook to what ?

Comment: I use a mini-Display Port to Display Port cable to connect it to my completely regular BenQ display, but it doesn't work with that cable anymore even though it used to work. For some reason it works just fine with HDMI though.

Comment: I have a hard time believing there are drivers for that kind of brands, it would just be a generic driver for DP and HDMI connections, otherwise new screens wouldn't work on OS X without an update.

Comment: I have just run into a variation of your problem. My Mac Pro (late 2013) was working fine under MacOS Sierra 10.12.5 with a 4K LG monitor attached via mini-DisplayPort (Mac side) to Display Port (monitor side). After 10.12.6 update, this doesn't work. Just a blank screen with "No Signal" displayed. Swapping back to an HDMI to HDMI connection works, but of course, I lose the 60Hz refresh and drop back to 30Hz. Quality control seems to continue to slip at Apple, Inc.

Comment: I have the same problem with a kensington sd3500v. Been working for years, displaying two additional screens from my macbook air. Updated today to 10.12.6 and it no longer works.